# Delphi Add items to cxcombobox on cxgrid without using oninitpopup event for column

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl, delphi-10.2-tokyo, tcxgrid

I am having a `CXGrid` with `cxGridTableView`, I have some 9 columns out of them some are having `cxcomboBox` , `cxcheckcombobox`, `cxMemo`  etc.

The existing grid is Orpheus table and the column is of type TOvcTCComboBox this adds items like this `OvcTCComboBox_Name.Items.Add('Name');`
How can we achieve this on `CXGrid` with `cxGridTableView`

```
1.  procedure SetCombobox(aCombo: TOvcTCComboBox; sTyp: string; bFirst: Bool; sSpr: string; sRetVal: string);

2.  procedure SetCombobox(aCombo: TCxComboBox; sTyp: string; bFirst: Bool; sSpr: string; sRetVal: string);
```

I have changed the procedure declaration from 1 to 2 and called the procedure with parameters as below

```
X_ABCD.SetCombobox(TCXComboBox(OvcTCComboBoxDOSI_Einh_.Properties),'GE',True,DDO_sSPRACHE,'TXT');
```

Still this is not working, How can this be fixed?

Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, you can use this to add items to a bound grid with a combobox in the first column

```
  TcxComboBoxProperties(cxGrid1DBTableView1Column1.Properties).Items.Add('Item1')
  TcxComboBoxProperties(cxGrid1DBTableView1Column1.Properties).Items.Add('Item2')
```

You'll find you can't directly translate your existing `SetCombobox` function, and so your existing code will be affected

Comment: I have implemented my SetComboBox procedure by passing the first parameter as `TCxGridColumn` and in the procedure I used the the same above statement you wrote to add items to combobox on grid.